# Getting box dimensions in class file

Tags: vertical-alignment, titles

I want to adjust vertical spacing after the title in a thesis class by measuring the title length (actually, height). To achieve this, I put the title in a box and compute the total height of the box.

First, commands to define the title and its styling:

```
\newcommand{\UL@maintitle}{}
\newcommand{\titre}[1]{\renewcommand{\UL@maintitle}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\UL@fonttitle}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\sffamily}
```

Next, the title box:

```
\newsavebox{\UL@titlebox}
\sbox{\UL@titlebox}{%
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering%
    \UL@fonttitle\UL@maintitle\par
  \end{minipage}}
```

Finally, computation the total box height:

```
\newlength{\UL@titleboxtotht}
\setlength{\UL@titleboxtotht}{\dimexpr\ht\UL@titlebox+\dp\UL@titlebox}
```

This works fine in a document (`.tex`) file itself. I get, say, that `\UL@titleboxtotht` is 48.48pt. With above commands defined in the class (`.cls`) file, I cannot get a hold of the dimension I'm looking for; I only get that `\UL@titleboxtotht` is 2.73pt. It seems the actual content of the box is never evaluated. Any idea?

Comment: There is a problem with `\setlength` statement; improper bracing. Does the class include the [`calc` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc)? Also, you can only calculate the title dimensions once it has been set. Would you be able to provide a complete minimal example that shows your usage within the special "thesis" class? Also provide a link to the `.cls` file.

Comment: Fixed the bracing; this was not the problem, just bad copy-pasting. Sorry for the noise. No calc package. "... once it has been set": that was my impression, but when/how is it set? When \titlepage is issued?

Comment: Where is the `.cls` located? Please provide a link. Also include a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) of your problem case. It may be related to the code, or the sequence of commands executed.

Comment: Ok, I put an edited and minimally commented version of the class file, a MWE and a required image file [in a zip archive](http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/pub/latex/ulthese2-test.zip). FWIW, the current official version of the class is on [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/ulthese).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to defer the measurement to when the title is known, which is when you are expanding `\pagetitre`; so I'd say

```
%% Here we play with the title (and subtitle)
\newsavebox{\UL@titlebox}
\newsavebox{\UL@subtitlebox}
\newlength{\UL@titleboxtotht}
\newlength{\UL@subtitleboxtotht}

\newcommand{\UL@measuretitle}{%
  \setbox\UL@titlebox=\vbox{\centering\UL@fonttitle\UL@maintitle}
  \setlength{\UL@titleboxtotht}{\dimexpr\ht\UL@titlebox+\dp\UL@titlebox}
  %% Repeat above commands for subtitle, if there is one
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{UL@hassubtitle}}{%
    \setbox\UL@subtitlebox=\vbox{\centering\UL@fontsubtitle\UL@subtitle}
    \setlength{\UL@subtitleboxtotht}{\dimexpr\ht\UL@subtitlebox+\dp\UL@subtitlebox}}
  {}%
}


%% Adjust spacing between title and "doc id" depending on height of
%% the title and subtitle block
\newlength{\UL@spacing}
\setlength{\UL@spacing}{90pt}

%% Define analogue of the \titlepage command   
\newcommand{\pagetitre}{{%
    \clearpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \SingleSpacing\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \centering
    \UL@fontbase
    %%%% COMPUTE THE DIMENSIONS
    \UL@measuretitle
    \addtolength{\UL@spacing}{-\UL@titleboxtotht}
    \addtolength{\UL@spacing}{-\UL@subtitleboxtotht}
    %%%%
    \ifthenelse{\UL@typenum > 1}{\vspace*{0pt}\par}{%
      \includegraphics[height=40px,keepaspectratio=true]{ul_p}\par}
    \vspace{72pt}
    \box\UL@titlebox
    \vspace{\baselineskip} %%%% SOME SPACE BETWEEN TITLE AND SUBTITLE
    \box\UL@subtitlebox
    \vspace{\UL@spacing}
    \UL@docid
    \vspace{72pt}
    {\UL@fontauthor\UL@author}\par
    \UL@details
    \vfill
    {\textcopyright} \UL@author, \UL@year\par
    \clearpage
  }}
```

Comment: Ah ha! That's the trick! Works exactly as expected, thanks very much!